# What Causes Mutt To Fail In This Way

Tags: email, mutt

When sending an email, the authentication and uploading stages exit successfully. After a long period with the message `Connecting to gmail.com`, the error message `Could not connect to gmail.com (No route to host).` occurs and the email is not sent. What causes this error and how might I fix it?

I do have my `smtp_url` set to port `587` of my stmp account URI.

Answer (score 0):

That's because there's not opened port tcp/587 (smtp + tls) on gmail.com. You should use **smtp.gmail.com**.